# Overfull hbox in description environment

Tags: line-breaking, description

I have a problem with description environment. The text exceeds the width of the page

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[francais]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=2.5cm}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\chapter{Some small hints}\label{hints}
\section{German Umlauts and other Language Specific Characters}\label{umlauts}
You can type german umlauts like 'ä', 'ö', or 'ü' directly in this file.
\begin{description}
\item [small item:] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\item [Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse consequat   accumsan sodales. Duis pulvinar sagittis porta. Mauris malesuada vehicula turpis,] sed ornare ante. In pulvinar ligula a leo lacinia, vel laoreet tortor auctor. Nullam in tinc] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

this is the output :[image]

Is there a solution to ensure that the text goes to a new line automatically ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with`sameline` option from the `enumitem` package. Incidentally, I changed the input enncoding to `utf8`, as it is more portable to another platform:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=2.5cm, showframe, nomarginpar}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\AtBeginDocument{\def\chaptername{Le Chapter}}
```

[image]

```
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\chapter{Some small hints}\label{hints}
\section{German Umlauts and other Language Specific Characters}\label{umlauts}
You can type german umlauts like 'ä', 'ö', or 'ü' directly in this file.

\begin{description}[style =sameline]
\item [small item:] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

\item [Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse consequat accumsan sodales. Duis pulvinar sagittis porta. Mauris malesuada vehicula turpis,] sed ornare ante. In pulvinar ligula a leo lacinia, vel laoreet tortor auctor. Nullam in tinc]
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Loading the `enumitem` gives you various style options for `description`.  For example `unboxed` allows multiline labels:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}

\usepackage[francais]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=unboxed]
\item [small item:] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\item [Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
  elit. Suspendisse consequat accumsan sodales. Duis pulvinar sagittis
  porta. Mauris malesuada vehicula turpis,] sed ornare ante. In
  pulvinar ligula a leo lacinia, vel laoreet tortor auctor. Nullam in
  tinc] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```